# Vue/Nuxt - Meta tags not working correctly

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, meta-tags

I have followed the meta tag [guidelines](https://masteringnuxt.com/blog/setting-up-nuxt-for-social-cards-and-meta-tags-to-improve-seo) for my application and used the [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fthomasbell.dev%2F), [LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/inspect/https:%2F%2Fthomasbell.dev%2F) & [Twitter](https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator) validators but its not working as expected.

**Facebook** is showing the correct tags but throwing the warning `The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.`

**LinkedIn** is not reading the og:image or og:type correctly.

**Twitter** is not showing the twitter:image.

Is there a problem within my code or maybe an error on the validator scraping the site?

```
meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { name: 'format-detection', content: 'telephone=no' },
      { name: 'msapplication-TileColor', content: "#da532c" },
      { name: 'theme-color', content: "#0a192f" },
      {
        hid: 'og:title',
        name: 'og:title',
        content: 'Thomas Bell - Developer',
      },
      {
        hid: 'description',
        name: 'description',
        content:
          'A self taught developer who loves to code and problem solve. I have a passion for learning and building useful tools to help people while promoting conservation for the planet. Check out my portfolio and get in touch!',
      },
      {
        hid: 'og:description',
        name: 'og:description',
        content:
          'A self taught developer who loves to code and problem solve. I have a passion for learning and building useful tools to help people while promoting conservation for the planet. Check out my portfolio and get in touch!',
      },
      {
        hid: 'og:url',
        name: 'og:url',
        content: 'https://thomasbell.dev/',
      },
      { hid: 'og:locale', name: 'og:locale', content: 'en_US' },
      { hid: 'og:type', name: 'og:type', content: 'website' },
      {
        hid: 'og:site_name',
        name: 'og:site_name',
        content: 'Thomas Bell - Web Developer',
      },
      {
        hid: 'og:image',
        name: 'og:image',
        itemprop: 'image',
        content: 'https://thomasbell.dev/images/portfolio.png',
      },
      { hid: "og:image:width", name: "og:image:width", content: "1200" },
      { hid: "og:image:height", name: "og:image:height", content: "630" },
      {

        hid: 'twitter:card',
        name: 'twitter:card',
        content: 'summary_large_image',
      },
      {
        hid: 'twitter:description',
        name: 'twitter:description',
        content:
          'A self taught developer who loves to code and problem solve. I have a passion for learning and building useful tools to help people while promoting conservation for the planet. Check out my portfolio and get in touch!',
      },
      {
        hid: 'twitter:title',
        name: 'twitter:title',
        title: 'Thomas Bell - Developer',
      },
      {
        hid: 'twitter:image',
        name: 'twitter:image',
        content: 'https://thomasbell.dev/images/portfolio.png',
      },
      {
        hid: 'twitter:site',
        name: 'twitter:site',
        content: '@tombell_95',
      },
      {
      hid: "twitter:creator",
      name: "twitter:creator",
      content: "@tombell_95",
    },
    ],
```

[image]

Comment: Did you figure it out? I have the same issue & code.

Comment: No I wasnt able to find a solution

Comment: I have just found out. You had probably ssr-only or client-only in the code so that page was not rendered on the server.